# Google Places API inconsistency

Tags: google-places-api

Adding expected types parameter changes response result in unexpected way.

Request 1:     https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=38.4551,-122.672045&radius=100&sensor=false&key=

Request 2:     https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=38.4551,-122.672045&radius=100&sensor=false&types=park&key=

Both requests should return place with *name: "Howarth Park"* since it is of a type park. And the funny thing is that increasing *radius=500* will bring back the expected result. But then how come it is returning it in the first place with no types parameter and the same radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way the Google Places API processes Search Requests.

The Places API will return up to 20 establishment results within the specified radius. Additionally, area identity results may be returned to to help identify the area the establishments are located.

If no type has been specified in the Places API Search Request, these area identity results **are not** strictly limited to the radius specified in the request, however when a type has been specified, additional area identity results **are** strictly limited to the radius specified in the request.